# Why does the Galaksija's latch include some kind of address remapping?

Tags: hardware, galaksija

The [Galaksija](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaksija_(computer)) has a 6 bit latch used for various bits and bobs, notably the part of the scanline counter which contributes to character generation, but also, it has a bit for clamping A7 high, and this bit is active low.

The portion of the schematic relevant to the question is highlighted in red:

[image: Annotated schematic]

Imagine the whole address space is chopped into blocks 128 bytes long. This will have the effect of mirroring every odd-numbered block to the preceding even-numbered block. I can imagine that this would be useful for refreshing some rare kind of DRAM, but this is not used in the Galaksija. So what does the Galaksija use the A7 clamp for?

Datasheets:

- [74138 1-of-8 / 74139 dual 1-of-4 Demultiplexer](http://ee-classes.usc.edu/ee459/library/datasheets/DM74LS138.pdf)
- [74174 Latch](http://ee-classes.usc.edu/ee459/library/datasheets/DM74LS174.pdf)
  (note that this datasheet also covers the 74175)
- [74251 Multiplexer](http://ee-classes.usc.edu/ee459/library/datasheets/DM74LS251.pdf)
- [6264 SRAM](http://www.cs.uml.edu/~fredm/courses/91.305/files/cy6264.pdf)

Comment: Based on my reading of a partial schematic I found, the MSB of the latch is indeed used to gate the A7 line to the RAM only.  It's SRAM, so no refresh required, but the refresh circuitry of the CPU is apparently used to assist the video output (ZX81 style).  It's obviously a deliberate feature but I don't know why.

Comment: I feel like I'm playing ADVENT looking at that schematic...

Comment: The original schematic is at http://retrospec.sgn.net/users/tomcat/Galaksija/MagScans/RACUN01/RACUN01-53.png, but doesn't seem to clarify matters. I can't read Serbian, but AFAICT the surrounding article text contains no reference to it.

Comment: @occipita I'm reverse-engineering the schematic as we speak.

Answer (score 4):

**This is not intended to be a full answer; it's just my take on what the hardware is doing.**

Note: There are undoubtedly errors below.

The description below follows all of the signals that feed in to `A7`.  It should make sense when read from top to bottom.

**U10 : 74139 dual 1-of-4 demux** ("Address decoder")

Outputs default `H`.

Left side on schematic:

```
A15 = /Enable

A13=L, A14=L, A15=L ⇒ /CS_ROM = L
A13=H, A14=L, A15=L ⇒ /Enable on the chip's other demux = L.
                      Also connects to /CE2 on the RAM via several NOT 
                      and NAND gates.  
                      The additional gates also hook into the output
                      of the other half of this gate and the Z80's 
                      refresh line (used for the video circuitry).
Other two outputs unused.
```

Right side on schematic:

```
A13=H, A14=L, A15=L ⇒ /Enable = L (as described above)

A11=L, A12=L, /Enable=L ⇒ Latch/Kbd(?) CS = L
                          This output also hooks into the afore-
                          mentioned circuitry hooked up to the RAM's
                          CE2 line.
Other three outputs unused.
```

**U6 : 74251 1-of-8 multiplexer**

This appears to be used for scanning the keyboard matrix.  It takes one of its inputs from one of the lines of interest but does not output to the circuit we're interested in.

This chip is one of the two chips connected to the `Latch/Kbd CS` line.

When `Latch/Kbd CS` is `L` then this chip's outputs are active.  When it's `H` the outputs are high-Z.

**U7 : 74138 1-of-8 Demux**

This chip is one of the two chips connected to the `Latch/Kbd CS` line.

Outputs default `H`.

Only one output is of interest on this chip (`Q7`).

```
/E0 = Latch/Kbd(?) CS
/E1 = MREQ
E2  = H

A0 (chip) = A3 (on the Z-80 bus)
A1 (chip) = A4 (on the Z-80 bus)
A2 (chip) = A5 (on the Z-80 bus)
```

`/E0`=`H`, `/E1`=`H`, `A0`=H, `A1`=H, `A5`=H ⇒ `Q7` = L

Or in other words:

`Latch/Kbd CS`=`H`, `/MREQ`<sub>Z80</sub>=`H`, `A3`<sub>Z80</sub>=H, `A4`<sub>Z80</sub>=H, `A5`<sub>Z80</sub>=H ⇒ `Q7` = L

**U17 : 3-input NOR gate**

The NOR gate's three inputs are `Q7` from the `U7` demux, `MREQ`<sub>Z80</sub>, and `Write`<sub>Z80</sub>.

Output is connected to the 74174 latch's `/CP` line.

**U8 : 74174 latch**

This latches the input (`D2`<sub>Z80</sub>..`D7`<sub>Z80</sub>) on the rising edge of `/CP`.

Inputs:
`/CP` : See `U17`, immediately above.
`D0`..`D5` = `D2`<sub>Z80</sub>..`D7`<sub>Z80</sub>

Outputs:

```
Q0         → Character generator C0, Line out
Q1, Q2, Q3 → Character generator C1, C2, C3
Q4         → Line out
Q5         → U18 NAND (left)
             This is the one we're interested in.
```

**U16 : 7400 quad 2-input NAND**

One gate is simply used to invert `A7`<sub>Z80</sub>.  The output of this, along with `Q5` from the latch are fed into a second NAND gate.  The output of this goes to `A7` on the 6264 SRAM.

## Synopsis

TBD.  First guess is that it might allow the currently-pressed keyboard keys to be read directly either to the Z80 or to RAM.

Answer (score 4):

Like the ZX80 and ZX81, the Galaksija uses the Z80's DRAM refresh as an address generator for display generation. During refresh, the Z80 places the contents of its R register on lines A0-A6, and the I register on A8-A16, but the A7 line is always zero. Therefore, in order to generate screen memory addresses with A7 set to 1, circuitry is required to force the A7 line high. This is what this bit of the latch is used for.

Only RAM addresses are affected by this, meaning that code in ROM used to generate the correct sequence of addresses can run unimpeded.

Comment: I thought it might be something obscure and stupid about the way the Z80 works.  Good to see that I was right, *and* that I didn't have to dig into the details myself too hard.

Comment: Just one nitpick: it's not the `A` register that's put on the address bus, but `I`. Other than that, R is 8 bits wide so it would have been enough to set the uppermost bit of R using `ld a,r` or whatever.

Comment: @OmarL - thanks, fixed. Got  confused because the A register supplies the upper address byte during IO operations, and I just assumed it would be the same...

Comment: @OmarL - I haven't checked the actual behaviour, but my copy of the Z80 user manual states that only bits 0-6 of the R register are placed on the bus during refresh cycles. It doesn't specify what the other bits are. Does bit 7 actually get used? If it does, did the designer perhaps not realise this?